# How to link a box value between to sheet, and make this link supporting a sorting into one or the other sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 sheets, and I want one of them to be filled with the values of the other one like that :

"sheet 1" who is the source sheet :

[image]

"sheet 2" who have some boxes filled with the value of the box 1 :

[image]

but the problem is that if I sort the value into the "sheet 1" in a different order, the value itself in the the "sheet 2" change like that :

first order :

"sheet 1"

[image]

"sheet 2"

[image]

new value on "sheet 2" after having re order the "sheet 1"

"sheet 1"

[image]

"sheet 2"

[image]

anyway to have a formula that make the box of the "sheet 2" not to change ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be done with formula, maybe an Apps Script?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than linking directly to the cell, use a key and VLOOKUP() or FILTER() to bring the appropriate data across. Whether that's the project name, an existing UID, or even just create a numbered column you can reference. Then use =ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(key,lookup_range,{index,index,index})) or =FILTER(range,column=UID)